# Call the JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe

i have simple JFRAME (create by Netbeans) and i want to call **frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL)** from another class. How to do call?

```
public class Myclass{

     public void Frame_normal{

       ...?
       ???frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);

     }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicaly you create an attribute in your class and you give it the reference to your JFrame.

```
 public class Myclass{

      JFrame frame;

      public MyClass(JFrame aFrame){
           this.frame = aFrame;
      }

      public void Frame_normal{


           frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);

      }

 }

 MyClass class = new Myclass(theJFrame);
 class.Frame_normal();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

1. Create the frame in the class where you want to call setState() function on it.
2. Create a getter method on that class where you are actually creating the Frame. Then use this getter to get your JFrame and call your method on it.
3. Make the JFrame public.(Not recommended)

Comment: How to make JFrame public with netbeans(generate JFrame form)? I searched the internet but found nothing.

Comment: Generating JFrame from NetBeans is a tool(utility). It will have it's corresponding code. change it's access modifier from private/default to public.